# Whirr: hadoop-proxy.sh not working

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, apache-whirr

I have installed Whirr and created an EC2 cluster. The cluster is created correctly and I can ssh to the nodes and check that Hadoop is working correctly. However, whenever I try to use the hadoop-proxy.sh, I get the following message:

```
bind: Cannot assign requested address
```

And if I try to see the HDFS in a different shell (I have previously configured the HADOOP_CONF_DIR variable), I get the following error:

```
13/11/29 05:15:09 WARN conf.Configuration: DEPRECATED: hadoop-site.xml found in the classpath. Usage of hadoop-site.xml is deprecated. Instead use core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml to override properties of core-default.xml, mapred-default.xml and hdfs-default.xml respectively
Bad connection to FS. command aborted. exception: Server IPC version 7 cannot communicate with client version 4
```

I have tried with different properties files when setting up the cluster, using CDH, without using it... But I am still getting the same error. This is the properties file that I am currently using to launch the cluster with Whirr:

```
whirr.cluster-name=otrotest
whirr.instance-templates=1 hadoop-namenode+yarn-resourcemanager+mapreduce-historyserver,2 hadoop-datanode+yarn-nodemanager
whirr.provider=aws-ec2
whirr.identity=MY_ID
whirr.credential=MY_SECRET_KEY
whirr.private-key-file=/home/hduser/.ssh/whirr_id_rsa
whirr.public-key-file=/home/hduser/.ssh/whirr_id_rsa.pub
whirr.env.MAPREDUCE_VERSION=2
whirr.env.repo=cdh4
whirr.hadoop.install-function=install_cdh_hadoop
whirr.hadoop.configure-function=configure_cdh_hadoop
whirr.mr_jobhistory.start-function=start_cdh_mr_jobhistory
whirr.yarn.configure-function=configure_cdh_yarn
whirr.yarn.start-function=start_cdh_yarn
whirr.hardware-id=t1.micro
whirr.image-id=us-west-2/ami-6aad335a
whirr.location-id=us-west-2
whirr.java.install-function=install_openjdk
whirr.java.install-function=install_oab_java
```

I am new to Whirr and I guess I am missing something... But I don't know how to solve this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the version of hadoop installed by Whirr, and that available on your local client machine? You have a mismatch so you'll need to update the client version to match that installed by Whirr

Comment: Ok, now that you say that... Yes, the versions are different. The one in the client is 1.2.1, and the one installed by Whirr was 2.0.1 or something similar. I'll fix that tomorrow (I left the computer at work) and see if I can connect correctly. But what about the `bind: Cannot assign requested address` message? I thought that meant that the connection was failing or something, but is that ok? Thank you very much! @ChrisWhite